# React Server side rendering with Express - warning on the client checksum & Styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I am new to React server side rendering , working on a small demo with `React , Redux , React router , Material UI`. The problem I am facing is the below warning. Unsure how the isomorphic styling and assets works with webpack.

I understood the pipeline how server side rendering work , please correct me if it is wrong.

- Using renderToString the React component get resolved to the HTML.
- Once the HTML renders on the client side , all the events , styling gets attached meaning react try to render the component on the client side again , if the component is already created it will create it again.
- If the component is already created or NOT is derived based on the Checksum.

Issue reported in GIT
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4466

Code
https://github.com/sabha/React-Redux-Router-MaterialUI-ServerSideRendering

> 'warning.js:44Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container
>   but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using
>   server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what
>   the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate
>   which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server
>   rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is
>   different on the client or server: (client)
>   0;text-align:center;mui-prepared:;-webki (server)
>   0;text-align:center;-webkit-user-select:'

Comment: You may want to take a look at this article - https://www.garysieling.com/blog/fixing-react-attempted-reuse-markup-container-checksum-invalid

Comment: There is small workaround https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter/issues/149

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [Razzle Material UI Styled Example](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example) project I am setting the user agent this way:

[server.js](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L30):

```
renderToString(<Application userAgent={request.headers['user-agent']} />)
```

[client.js](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example/blob/master/src/client.js#L6):

```
hydrate(<Application userAgent={navigator.userAgent} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

[Main.js](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example/blob/master/src/application/Main.js#L29):

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(properties, context) {
        super(properties, context)

        this.muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
            userAgent: properties.userAgent
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={this.muiTheme}></MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

It works well and I think it is correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Material-UI, with its inline-style approach to styling elements, has this gotcha with respect to server-side rendering:

On the client, MaterialUI rendering only adds inline styles specific to the browser that is running the app.  But on the server, you aren't in a browser and so how to know *which* specific style rules to use so that the rendered HTML matches the client-rendered HTML and avoids the React warning?

They have documentation on how to solve the issue.  Essentially it means ensuring you set the user agent string (captured from the HTTP Request Header) before doing your server side rendering.

This is from their [serverside rendering documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/server-rendering):

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/MuiThemeProvider';
import {green100, green500, green700} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary1Color: green500,
    primary2Color: green700,
    primary3Color: green100,
  },
}, {
  avatar: {
    borderColor: null,
  },
  userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'],
});

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <div>Hello world</div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Brandon.  In my `server.js` file I am passing the user-agent which I receive in the express request header `const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({userAgent: req.headers['user-agent']});  `.

Answer (score 1):

> (client) 0;text-align:center;**mui-prepared:**;-webki
>   (server) 0;text-align:center;-webkit-user-select:

You will notice that the difference between the two is extra `mui-prepared` that is not present in the server render. There is a note about this at the bottom of the [server rendering guide](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/server-rendering) in the docs.

> In order to make sure our style transformations are only applied once, we add an additional property to each style when process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'.

It looks like you have `process.env.NODE_ENV=production` only on the server (this was the case for me).

Comment: Hi, Im getting this error with Racket boilerplate wihle running on dev, should I change process.env or this error will dissapear on production. Thanks

Comment: @Matt Cole Setting NODE_ENV to production completely change things everywhere.